# Gradle build error: Cannot invoke method on null object

Tags: gradle

My project set up has 2 projects. Project 2 is dependent on jar file of Project 1.

Project 1 is built using maven and the dependency is available in .m2

build.gradle file has the dependency

```
compile group: 'com.test.sample', name: 'sample', version:'1.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

settings.gradle has

```
rootProject.name = 'project'
include 'project2' 'project3'
```

when I am executing the build, I am getting the following error

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'project'.
> Cannot invoke method project2() on null object
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a comma between your includes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

include takes a list, so you need commas between the entries:

```
include 'project2', 'project3'
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that without the comma, 'project2' is seen as a method and 'project3' its first parameter,